# nodejs multer file upload, path contains double slashes

Tags: node.js, fs, multer

I am working on image upload via nodejs and multer module and this is the code im using:

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function(req, res, next) {
    var tmp_path = req.file.path,
        target_path = __dirname + '/public/uploads/' + req.file.originalname,

        src = fs.createReadStream(tmp_path),
        dest = fs.createWriteStream(target_path);

    src.pipe(dest);
    fs.unlink(tmp_path); //deleting the tmp_path

    src.on('end', function() {
        res.json({
            success: true,
            file: '/uploads/' + req.file.originalname
        });
    });

    src.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('err', err);
        res.json({
            success: false
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is that sometimes (it occures randomly) error callback is triggered, with this contents:

[image]

So it looks like additional slashes are added to the path which causes script not to find temp location and returns error, maybe someone encountered this problem and can help ;)

Comment: There are no double slashes in the actual string. What you are seeing is the *string literal* version since the object being shown was passed to `util.inspect()`, which formats string values in this way. One advantage to showing the literal version in this way is that it allows you to easily see control characters (e.g. \n, \t, etc.) more easily. You can also copy and paste it as-is in code and it will just work without modifications.

Comment: Additionally, you should *never* use the `originalname` (at least as-is --
 you could hash the name I suppose if you really wanted/needed to) since that is a client-supplied value and *could* contain malicious characters to trick you into overwriting sensitive/important files.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the unlink after success message is sent, pipe is asynchronous so might be executing after the delete.

```
 src.on('end', function() {
        res.json({
            success: true,
            file: '/uploads/' + req.file.originalname
        });
        fs.unlink(tmp_path)
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code in order to get rid of this error...

try:- path.replace("\\","/");

This will definitely solve your problem.